# How to pass variables to ASP query

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am an ASP beginner trying to make a very simple page. The functionality is to accept two inputs from the user and display a report based on those on the next page. The data for the report is fetched a SQL query on the ASP page.

This is what I have done till now:

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;
                       Data Source=şemam;
                       User Id=xyz;
                       Password=xyz;"
aranan = Request("aranan")

Set objRs = objConn.Execute("select * from my_department where user_id = <input from user>")
if objRs.BOF and objRs.eof then
  response.end
end if
```

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find how to properly pass the user input in the query.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` as a placeholder, then pass the parameters into the [Execute method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
dim paramArray(0)
paramArray(0) = 123
Set objRs = objConn.Execute("select * from my_department where user_id = ?", paramArray)
```

Comment: +1 because I have been working with Classic ASP forever and never knew you could pass parameters that way.

Answer (score 1):

To send parameters to a database query you need to use a command-object.

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;" & _
             "Data Source=şemam;" & _
             "User Id=xyz;" & _
             "Password=xyz;"
aranan = Request("aranan")

Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM my_department WHERE user_id = ?"
objCmd.CommandType = 1

Set objRs = objCmd.Execute(, array(aranan))
if not objRs.EOF then
' Do whatever you need to with the result...
end if
objRs.Close
objConn.Close
```

Don't end the response before you closed the connection otherwise you will end up exhausting your connectionpool.